# if Innerhtml length is greater, add class to its element

Tags: jquery, parent, innerhtml, addclass

i want it to control the text length inside every LI A, and if its greater than 5, then automatically add a class 'long' to its corresponding LI. So far i have this, but not working:

html:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="">Kodu</a></li>
    <li><a href="">VägaPikkSõna</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Teenused</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Kontakt</a></li>
</ul>
```

script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var x = document.getElementById('menu').getElementsByTagName('a');

    for(i=0; i<x.length; i++){              
        if(x[i].innerHTML.length > 5){
            $(this).parent().addClass('long')
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menu a").each(function() {
        if($(this).text().length>5){
            $(this).parent().addClass('long');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menu a').addClass(function() {
        return this.innerHTML.length > 5 ? 'long' : '';
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xUr3L/)